# The argument type 'Future<List<Uint8List>> Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<List<Uint8List>>?'

Tags: flutter, dart

argument and parameter type seem is same.

why always show error

```
                      FutureBuilder<List<Uint8List>>(
                          future: () async {
                            return <Uint8List>[
                              (await rootBundle.load(Res.sign_wangwenshuo))
                                  .buffer
                                  .asUint8List(),
                              (await rootBundle.load(Res.sign_welai))
                                  .buffer
                                  .asUint8List(),
                            ];
                          },
                          builder: SizedBox()),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

type is mismatch。
require a future but I provide a function.

> change to the following

```
 Future<List<Uint8List>> future() async {
    return <Uint8List>[
      (await rootBundle.load(Res.sign_wangwenshuo)).buffer
          .asUint8List(),
      (await rootBundle.load(Res.sign_welai)).buffer
          .asUint8List(),
    ];
  }

FutureBuilder<List<Uint8List>>(
       future: future();
       builder: SizedBox()),
```